# Calculating the age of the empty universe from the Hubble's constant

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, universe

[image]

This is from p.120 of Ta-Pei Cheng's Relativity, Gravitation and Cosmology. I cannot understand the way the book calculated the age of the empty universe. The velocity $v$ of expansion is proportional to the distance $d$. That means the expansion velocity has not been constant. But why does the book conclude the age of universe from simply dividing the distance $d$ from the velocity of the current moment? Is there something that I am missing? I need help.

Comment: It is a limit estimation

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: That it is just an estimate that indeed does not fit to observations. They clearly state that in an empty universe H is supposed to be constant in time

Answer (score 1):

An empty universe never changes.  Also, its value of $H_0$ never changes, and using the Friedmann equation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation

$H(t) = H_0 = 1.$

Therefore

$(1/a) (da/dt) = 1,$ and $da/dt = a.$

Therefore

$dt = da/a$, and $t = ln(a) + const.$

Therefore

$a = const$ x $e^t.$

Therefore the age is not determinable, since there is no way to choose one value for the constant in preference to another.